# Pickle both class variables and instance variables?

Tags: python, pickle

The [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) states that "when class instances are pickled, their class’s data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled." Can anyone provide a recipe for including class variables as well as instance variables when pickling and unpickling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `dill` instead of pickle, and code exactly how you probably have done already.

```
>>> class A(object):
...   y = 1
...   x = 0
...   def __call__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...     return self.x + self.y
... 
>>> b = A()
>>> b.y = 4
>>> b(2)
6
>>> b.z = 5
>>> import dill
>>> _b = dill.dumps(b)
>>> b_ = dill.loads(_b)
>>> 
>>> b_.z
5
>>> b_.x
2
>>> b_.y
4
>>>
>>> A.y = 100
>>> c = A()
>>> _c = dill.dumps(c)
>>> c_ = dill.loads(_c)
>>> c_.y
100
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution, thank you! I'll upvote you as soon as I'm able.

Comment: I'm curious though, can anyone provide an alternative solution using only standard library functions?

Comment: Yes, `dill` just uses `copy_reg`, `save_reduce`, and `save_global` under the covers, so you could do the same… it'd just be more work on your part.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using the standard library functions by using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`:

```
class A(object):
  y = 1
  x = 0

  def __getstate__(self):
    ret = self.__dict__.copy()
    ret['cls_x'] = A.x
    ret['cls_y'] = A.y
    return ret

  def __setstate__(self, state):
    A.x = state.pop('cls_x')
    A.y = state.pop('cls_y')
    self.__dict__.update(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using only standard library modules.  Simply execute the following code block, and from then on pickle behaves in the desired way.  As Mike McKerns was saying,  `dill` does something similar under the hood.

Based on relevant discussion found [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods).

```
import copy_reg


def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)


def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)


copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)
```