# Pickling and unpickling of class variables are working. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    x = "Cannot be pickled"

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

hello = Foo(a = 10)

with open("foo.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(hello, f)

with open("foo.pickle", "rb")  as f:
    world = pickle.load(f)
    print(f"world.a: {world.a}, world.x: {world.x}")
```

**Output:**

> world.a: 10, world.x: Cannot be pickled

In the above code pickling and unpickling of class variables works fine for me. But in this stackoverflow link [Pickle both class variables and instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409964/pickle-both-class-variables-and-instance-variables/) it says we can't pickle class variables and alternate solution are given using dill module.

Can anyone explain why its working for me?

Comment: A class is an instance too...

Comment: Also, you should link to the question, not your deleted post

Comment: The default `pickle` doesn't serialize the class along with the object, instead, it merely keeps a reference to the class, which is looked up upon deserialization. Which is exactly what is happening here

Comment: Edited the link.

Comment: So what you are saying, say if the Foo.x is modified in some class function and if I try to pickle and unpickle that value won't be retained say if try to unpickle in a different computer which has the exact class definition?

Comment: @Praburaj That's correct. `x` comes from the class, not the instance that was pickled. Put `Foo.x = "new value"` before the second `with` and you'll see the result.

Comment: Yes I have verified it Thanks for the explanation @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as one.py

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    x = "Cannot be pickled"

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    @classmethod
    def foo_class_method(cls):
        cls.x = "can be pickled"
    

hello = Foo(a = 10)
Foo.foo_class_method()

with open("foo.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(hello, f)
```

Save this one in separate file say two.py

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    x = "Cannot be pickled"

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    @classmethod
    def foo_class_method(cls):
        cls.x = "can be pickled"

with open("foo.pickle", "rb")  as f:
    world = pickle.load(f)
    print(f"world.a: {world.a}, world.x: {world.x}")
```

**Output:**

> world.a: 10, world.x: Cannot be pickled

If you see in one.py file eventhough x value is modified in foo_class_method() but during unpickling its not reflected.

This is because the default pickle doesn't serialize the class along with the object, instead, it merely keeps a reference to the class, which is looked up upon deserialization - Answered by @juanpa.arrivillaga